# Print all the permutations using recursion

Tags: c, recursion

I coded as below to print all the permutations of three number :1,2,3.

***But the output is:***
1,1,1
1,1,2
1,1,3
1,2,1
1,2,2
1,2,3

***The code is as follows:***

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void perm(int);

int a[10],l=2;

int main()
{
    int k;
    k=0;
    perm(k);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void perm(int k)
{
    int i;
    for(a[k]=1;a[k]<=3;a[k]++)
    {
        if(k==2)
        {
            for(i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                printf("%d ",a[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            k++;
            perm(k);
        }
    }
}
```

Please give the correct code.

Comment: What is the purpose of that hard-coded `if (k == 2)` condition?

Comment: The `(k == 2)` condition seems fine. But you need to check a[k] was not already choose before.

Comment: You need to keep track of which numbers have been used. And only use numbers that aren't already in the array.

Comment: [This](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/) would be a good starting point

Comment: @user3386109, it has to print all permutaion of three number. can have repeating digits

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation Fix question please.

Comment: whatever it may be, pl. correct my code

Comment: Just replace `k++; perm(k);` with `perm(k+1);`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you increment `k`? `k` should not change for a given call to `perm()`.

Also it's a bit too bad to be stuck with 3 permutations, you can easily generalize this way:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

static void perm(int, int);
static void all_perm(int);

int a[10];

int main()
{
    all_perm(3);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void all_perm(int n)
{
    perm(0, n);
}

void perm(int k, int n)
{
    if (k == n)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", a[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for(a[k]=1; a[k] <= n; a[k]++)
        {
            perm(k + 1, n);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Well, what you name permutations are not permutations.

Comment: @PranavSaxena Mathematics name for this **is not permutation**.

Answer (score 0):

The logic that I have used is to some extent similar to yours.
I have included the entire code to make it clear.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void recn(int*,int,int);
void print_arr(int*,int);
    void main()
    {
        int arr[3] = {1,2,3};
        recn(arr,3,0);
    }

    void print_arr(int *arr, int n){
        int i;
        for(i = 0,printf("\n"); i < n; printf("%d",arr[i++]));
    }

    void recn(int *arr, int n, int l) {
    int i, j, f, k, xx = 0;
    static int tst[15], a[14]={0};

    if (l == n) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            tst[i] = arr[a[i]];
        }
        print_arr(tst,n);
        return;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        f = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < l; j++)
            if (a[j] == i)
                f = 1;

        if (!f) {
            a[l] = i;
            recn(arr, n, l + 1);
        }
    }
}
```